# When was my indexes in the database fragmented?

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, index-tuning

I am trying to create a script that finds the index fragmentation, have it log to a table that I can query each time it runs. I need to fins out specifically **what time** my indexes in a table get fragmented. Below is the script I have so far to find the index fragmentation. What can I add to:

1. find the time indexes are fragmented
2. have it log to a table

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT S.name as 'Schema',
T.name as 'Table',
I.name as 'Index',
DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
DDIPS.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS DDIPS
INNER JOIN sys.tables T on T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
and I.name is not null
AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30
and DDIPS.page_count > 1000
ORDER BY DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

Comment: This information isn't collected by default. You can add a trace to poll for page splits using either the XE page_split event or sniff the transaction log using XE (the later has possibly quite hefty overhead) and then read this trace.

Answer (score 1):

you can collect avg_fragmentation_in_percent information over time (e.g., every 5 minutes) and then you can see how and when fragmentation moves through the hours...

In this way you create the table...

```
SELECT
S.name as 'Schema',
T.name as 'Table',
I.name as 'Index',
DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
DDIPS.page_count

CAST(getdate() as datetim2(5)) AS collection_time
INTO dob.mytable

FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS     DDIPS
INNER JOIN sys.tables T on T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
and I.name is not null
AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30
and DDIPS.page_count > 1000
---ORDER BY DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

and then...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable([Schema],[Tbale],[Index],avg_fragmentation_in_percent,page_count,collection_time)

SELECT S.name as 'Schema',
T.name as 'Table',
I.name as 'Index',
DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
DDIPS.page_count
CAST(getdate() as datetim2(5)) AS collection_time
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS     DDIPS
INNER JOIN sys.tables T on T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
and I.name is not null
AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30
and DDIPS.page_count > 1000
---ORDER BY DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

Comment: Good point potentially easier than having a trace running. Note that collecting this isn't free either, so implement with care.

Comment: I could do that, but I wouldnt be able to do that out of business hours, so I would need to create a job. What can I add to my query that will log the info to a table?

Comment: You can find it into my answer. It could have some weight, so my suggestion is, after an initial review, to focus on problematic indexes.